# Building Android game in Unity 4.3.4 does not succeed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

The build does not work.

During build I have messages:

> Android SDK is outdated. SDK Platform tool version 0<16. Android SDK
>   is missing required platform api. Minimuim platform required is
>   Android 4.0 (API level 14).

This happens though:

1) I have in Android SDK manager the following installed (as seen in Android Studio):

- Tools - all 12 items,
- Android L (API 20, L preview) - all 7 itmes,
- Android 4.4W (API 20) - all 5 items.

  In particular, I have everything with API 20 installed

2) I have a correct path to main folder of Android SDK location in Unity Preferneces -> External Tools

I'll appreciate any help or hints.

Answer (score 0):

Press `continue` the next time you get it. Keep pressing it everytime that update message pops up. It's just Unity asking you to have the latest SDK package to build with the latest improvements in Android SDK, which is not necessarily mandatory. If Android updates would come 3-4 times a week,you can't be bothered with updating so often.

And when you finally decide it's time to update, or feel like it just some time later,
open up the SDK Manager (inside android-sdk folder), and update (don't check the sources, docs, and android emulator images; you don't need them. Just check core packages and necessary google APIs.).